# Should I correct a mistake for the camera-ready version even though the reviewers missed that mistake?

Tags: publications, conference

So the mistake is not a major bug, the contributions of the paper remain the same, but still, I feel it was a silly statistical error. Can I correct it, even if the reviewers missed catching it?

Comment: That depends on the exact nature of the mistake. When it's "not a major bug" what is it, exactly? In my view, every word below depends on that exposition. I see "bugs", here, as obvious typographical errors. Do you see this instance as something else?

Answer (score 77):

Yes, you should if you can. Presumably the reviewers are not the last people who will be reading  the text.

Comment: The sooner corrections are made the better.

Answer (score 62):

While the [answer by markvs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/184573/135841) already tells you the right course of action, I think the following addendum is important:

The phrase "*even if the reviewers missed catching it*" indicates that you might have an inaccurate impression of the peer review process and should maybe change your perspective on it:

- As an important part of scientific quality ensurance, peer review serves several purposes. One purpose is to **decrease the probability** that a published paper contains errors. It is **not a guarantee** that a published paper does not contain any errors.
- It is **not** among the purposes of peer review to partially relieve the authors of their responsibility for the correctness of their results. If your readers find a mistake in your paper, they will blame you for it, not the reviewers.

Given these two points, it is clear that you should take all necessary measures to make your paper as correct as you possibly can, also if the reviewers overlooked a mistake.

**Important note.** If you make non-trivial changes after the completion of the peer review process, I strongly recommend to inform the handling editor of these changes - the editor then has the opportunity to approve (or, sometimes maybe, disapprove) the changes; and if they think that the changes are also in need of peer review, they then also have the opportunity to send the revised file to the reviewers once again. (EDIT: As pointed out by Danica in a comment, in some fields and for some publication venues this last paragraph does not apply.)

Comment: This! You should be clear that *if* there is a mistake in the paper, that is **your** mistake. It's your paper, your mistakes, everything in the paper is **yours**. Everything. Everyone else just "helps" you and may set a minimum quality standard to allow you publication, but it's up to you - and attributed to you - to publish great or bad stuff.
One point to maybe add: make sure to **record** the change in a changelog, mention it somewhere.

Comment: Or perhaps the impression was that it might not be OK to change a reviewed paper, because that would mean publishing something that has not fully been reviewed (pedantic, but technically true). If so, the question is asking whether changing it is "allowed" despite this. (yes, and encouraged even)

Comment: @Mayou36: Thanks for your comment! Yes, indeed, I should have added that one should mention post peer review changes (if they are not trivial, such as typos or small language issues) to the handling editor. I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: @tjalling: Yes, that might also be an intended meaning of the question. The last paragraph that I now added hopefully clarifies for the OP what they can do to ensure that the changes are allowed.

Comment: For [tag:conference] publications, at least in CS, it is usually the case that there is not a way to communicate with the "handling editor" after acceptance (generally called an "area chair" or "meta-reviewer" in my area), and there is absolutely no expectation that one do so. In the case of extremely-major changes, you should perhaps communicate with the program chairs. For relatively small changes (even on the scale of, say, swapping out a nontrivial section of a proof), this is not needed, and you should just do your very best to ensure that your correction is itself correct.

Comment: The last paragraph is important: Don't dismiss the possibility of your "fix" being erroneous itself. Maybe your fix makes the paper worse, so you should definitely inform and make sure it is approved.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck Don't you think far from "that might also be an intended meaning of the question…" it was at least the main, if not the only point?

I think the way you explained what "even if the reviewers missed catching it" meant, indicates it's you, not def anonymous, who might have an inaccurate impression of the peer review process and should maybe change your perspective on it.

Comment: @Falco Other than suggesting that all of us should always think twice, how was "The last paragraph is important: Don't dismiss the possibility of your "fix" being erroneous itself. Maybe your fix makes the paper worse, so you should definitely inform and make sure it is approved" helpful? Would you mind explaining what "camera ready" means to you, or how anything else could matter; preferably both?

Comment: @Danica: Thanks a lot for your comment! I included a remark at the end where your point is now mentioned.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your point. Could you clarify with which part of my perspective on the peer review process you disagree?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Don't you think far from a potential "intended meaning of the question…" it was at least the main, and prolly the only point? Can you follow that much?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Yes, I understood from the first sentence of your comment that you interpreted the question differently than I did. What I do not (yet) understand is the second sentence of your (first) comment.

Comment: @JochenGlueck If you haven't time to cite the second sentence of my first comment, why expect me to look it up? It's good that you see you interpreted the question differently, and would you like to build something useful on that, or try to make it into an argument or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I am not interested in an argument, I am interested in understanding your point. You wrote "*[...] indicates it's you, not def anonymous, who might have an inaccurate impression of the peer review process and should maybe change your perspective on it.*" As I said before: Could you clarify with which part of my perspective on the peer review process you disagree?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I suggest you should not change something on the paper without letting at least a second pair of eyes see and vet your change. In the review process the reviewers should be informed about your change and have a chance to review it as well (no matter how sure you are by yourself your fix is making the paper better)

Comment: @Jochen Glueck We’re being called to account for extended discussion, so this is my last Post here, apart from the Question all of us should have Asked at the top.

As before, what interest d’you think peer-reviewers have in camera readiness?

Markvs was correct but your addendum seemed to confuse the roles of peer reviewer and copy editor, as witness that odd "even if the reviewers missed catching it"
  
More…

Comment: Further… Of course the editor’s job is to disapprove changes, or refer again to the reviewers… and the point of camera-readiness is that this Question is either past the stage you’re thinking of or so obscure, there’s prolly no hope.
  
Did you not notice, the idea that one purpose of peer review is to decrease the probability of errors is almost a direct contradiction of how it’s not to partially relieve authors of responsibility?

More…

Comment: Further… Who would not take all measures to make a paper correct? Crucially, what use had “also if the reviewers overlooked a mistake…” if not to say that the author should sometimes proceed alone with a late correction?
  
Important note: before any slightest change at any stage, I insist the editor be consulted, doubly so if an author who’s already reached camera-readiness needs the duties of an editor explaining.

Answer (score 3):

It is *your* responsibility to ensure that the text is correct.

It is not the responsibility of the reviewers.  The reviewers only act as gatekeepers to offer an expert opinion and state that the paper looks to be correct and interesting.  They will not check every detail (necessarily) and will likely not see small mistakes and errors.

Answer (score -5):

The Question isn't really clear but if, from another perspective, you're Asking whether the fact that there are reviewers absolves you of responsibility for accuracy then no; of course it never could.

When I worked in publishing everyone, at every level, knew that if anyone - specifically including the telephone sanitisers - questioned anything, the correct procedure was to amend the wording of that thing.

Of course right there and then, I could give the sanitiser an explanation, and so what?

What explanation could I give to 50-100,000 readers, after publication?

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question from an academic perspective, and it clearly misrepresents the role of the reviewers.

Comment: @Massimo. Sorry but if that's your view then you have no idea either what publishing involves, or what the role of reviewers is. If you don't follow that, look above mine at Tom's Answer.

Comment: I think your first paragraph technically offers an answer to the question, even if it adds nothing to Tom's answer (so, I will decline the "not an answer" flags). That said: I found the remaining three paragraphs very hard to follow. Moreover: I think there may be some confusion about the distinction between academic reviewers and other types of publishing (e.g., for undergraduate textbooks) -- proofreaders in the latter may indeed spend months polishing every word, but reviewers for the former do not tend to do much polishing at all.

Comment: @cag51 The Question still isn't clear and if you looked at it in other ways, could you still see no difference between conceptual problems and simple factual errors?

Don't you see that the mention of "camera-ready" moves the Question outside the range of review, or any responsibility of reviewers, and despite your experience, should show it it to be about publishing in general, not in any way specific to academia?

Try it, why not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This is the academia site, so all questions (and answers) are assumed to be about academia; otherwise, they would be off-topic (for questions) or non-responsive (for answers). Further, if one feels that the question is not clear, we should seek clarification in the comments rather than posting answers (in any case, this question mentions "papers" not "books"). As for the substantive issues: I'm not sure that we're understanding one another, but that's okay, we don't need to agree. Cheers!

Comment: @cag51 To put it another way, what possible interest could reviewers have in camera-ready anything?